# How to do this without unchecked?

Tags: c#, unchecked

a few months ago I wrote this code because it was the only way I could think to do it(while learning C#), well. How would you do it? Is `unchecked` the proper way of doing this?

```
unchecked //FromArgb takes a 32 bit value, though says it's signed. Which colors shouldn't be.
{
  _EditControl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)0xFFCCCCCC);
}
```

Comment: I think you can split the value into Color.FromArgb(0xFF,0xCC,0xCC,0xCC); This should work without casting errors.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I just came across it, and I'm curious as to why you'd not want to just use `unchecked`. Was it a curiosity question, or was there an actual problem? I'd have just used unchecked.

Comment: @Jon at the time I'd consider myself a junior at C#. So I was wondering if `unchecked` was bad. Now, I'd probably stick with `unchecked` though instead of the marked answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break down the components of the int and use the `FromArgb()` overload that takes them separately:

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb( 0xFF, 0xCC, 0xCC, 0xCC);
```

Answer (score 6):

It takes a signed int b/c this dates back to the time when VB.NET didn't have unsigned values. So in order to maintain compatibility between C# and VB.NET, all the BCL libraries utilize signed values, even if it does not make logical sense.

Comment: Another way to look at this is that CLS-compliant languages are not required to understand uint. So the libraries generally avoid uint.

Comment: Other classes (like `System.Net.IPAddress`) decided to use the larger signed 64-bit type so people could more easily pass in a full 32-bit unsigned value to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods can hide this:

```
public static Color ToColor(this uint argb)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(unchecked((int)argb));
}

public static Color ToColor(this int argb)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(argb);
}
```

Usage:

```
0xff112233.ToColor(); 
0x7f112233.ToColor();
```

Seems like they're should be another notation (like 0v12345678) or some other way to work around this issue.